# Please explain Android permission protection_signature explanation

Tags: android, android-permissions

I got the below explanation from Android documentation, about the new permission model in Android M Preview. Please explain the texts in bold in simple words because I am confused.

If the app requests permissions in the manifest that fall under PROTECTION_SIGNATURE, **and the app is signed with the same certificate as the app that declared those permissions,** the system grants the requesting app those permissions on installation. Apps cannot request signature permissions at runtime.

Comment: I have the same question and confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Apps can define their own permissions via the manifest. This is referring to those permissions. So if I publish 2 apps, both signed with the same certificate, and app#1 *defines* a new permission with signature level protection and app#2 *uses* that permission (by stating so in its manifest) then the system will automatically grant the permission to app#2. Note that this is not new to Android Marshmallow. Only the selective grant/revoke is.

This article will help to explain permissions in general under Android: http://hiqes.com/android-security-part-2

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess.

there are two apps, A and B, they was signed with the same certificate.
first at all, user start using A app, and request permissions `EXAMPLE_PERMISSION` under `PROTECTION_SIGNATURE`, then system gives a dialog and tips user that he need to grant it. user click GRANT.

And then, user launch B app, B app wants the same permission, the `EXAMPLE_PERMISSION`, and when it requests the permission, system auto grant that.

Because of A app has granted it, and A and B have the same certificate.

I guess so.